# Actualización de aplicaciones en Android

Tags: android, app, apk

Programé una aplicación en Java para Android, esta cada vez que inicia compara su versión con la versión de un APK que tengo en un servidor gratuito ya que no tengo la cuenta de desarrollador de Google Play, dependiendo de la condición mi app descarga el APK a mi dispositivo para instalar la nueva actualización, el asunto es que si el usuario le da cancelar a la instalación, este puede buscar en las carpetas del dispositivo y copiar el apk. Cómo puedo hacer si este proceso de descarga e instalación es independiente de mi aplicación, ya que creo que de eso se encarga el S.O.
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta, quieres borrar tu archivo cuando el usuario cancele la instalación?

Comment: Si, pero como detecto esa acción. Es que para actualizar una app es necesario descargar el APK para luego proceder a la insatalación y así quedar actualizado, creo que así es como funciona, soy un poco nuevo en esto. Es que vi que si el usuario cancela la acualización o instalación luego puede buscar en las carpetas el APK y utilizarlo a su antojo.

Comment: existen aplicaciones que te permiten "compartir" aplicaciones **ya instaladas** y no hay mucho que puedas hacer respecto a los archivos que son del usuario, caso contrario, deberías saber donde se descarga tu APK, el nombre de la misma, y borrarlo directamente.

Comment: Ok comprendo bien eso. Sin embargo sé la ubicación donde se descarga mi APK, y yo lo elimino una vez que se actualizó mi app, el asunto es cuando el usuario cancela la instalación (desde el S.O). Y te agradezco el aporte..

Comment: podrías hacer que tu app busque si existe el apk en la ubicación de descarga, y borrarlo, antes de que realize el proceso de actualización, no es totalmente efectivo, pero es lo mejor que puedes hacer para "solventar" tu problema

Comment: No te va a ser posible hacer una app que se descargue y se actualice por si misma ya que eso requeriría que cierre su propio proceso para poder ejecutar la instalación.
Tu mejor alternativa sería tener una app secundaria que se encargue del proceso de descarga e "instalación" para asegurarse que se eliminen los archivos utilizados.